# Is roofing felt/felt shingle breathable?

Tags: roof

I'm thinking of putting either these [bitumen shingles](https://www.roofinglines.co.uk/product/apex-hexagonal-bitumen-shingles-3-tab-grey), or standard roofing felt, on top of a barrel sauna to stop it leaking.

While I'm at it I thought I might add some air bubble/aluminium [insulation roll](https://www.building-supplies-online.co.uk/superfoil-general-purpose-multifoil-insulation-roll-1m-x-7m-roll.html) but I wouldn't want to reduce breathability of the shingles, if they have any in the first place. If they do then I suspect the wood needs it to shed moisture from the sauna steam or it will rot. If they don't then I suspect this isn't a problem as it is a common sauna design.

So does the bitumen felt/shingle layer breathe at all?

Comment: Felt paper with a shingles over it is permeable. In other words it will let moisture pass through so it does not allow condensate to build up. So I guess that is kinda breathable.... Careful where you put the roll sheet, it will trap the moisture

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing here though? "shingles" seems to have a variety of meanings; I'm not talking about two separate layers felt+shingles but a single roofing felt layer. (with possibly insulation underneath, or not if it's a bad idea)

Comment: I see now, the proper question, shingles OR felt, but yes either is breathable.

Comment: I've never seen any bitumen based product claiming to be breathable.